# How do I scrape data from JavaScript website?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to scrape data from [this dynamic JavaScript website](http://www.sotaventogalicia.com/en/real-time-data/historical). Since the page is dynamic I am using Selenium to extract the data from the table. Please suggest me how to scrape the data from the dynamic table. Here is my code.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import lxml.html as LH
import requests

# specify the url
urlpage = 'http://www.sotaventogalicia.com/en/real-time-data/historical'
print(urlpage)

# run firefox webdriver from executable path of your choice
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Shresth Suman/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
##driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:/Users/Shresth Suman/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64/geckodriver.exe')

# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)
# execute script to scroll down the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
# sleep for 5s
time.sleep(5)
# driver.quit()


# find elements by xpath
##results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='div_taboa']//table[@id='taboa']/tbody")
##results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='page-title']")
##results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='div_main']/h2[1]")
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'frame_historicos']")
print(results)
print(len(results))


# create empty array to store data
data = []
# loop over results
for result in results:
    heading = result.text
    print(heading)
    headingfind = result.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')
    # append dict to array
    data.append({"head" : headingfind, "name" : heading})
# close driver 
driver.quit()
###################################################################



# save to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
# write to csv
df.to_csv('testsot.csv')
```

**I want to extract data from 2005 till present with Averages/Totals of 10 min which gives me data for only one month.**

Comment: Please mentioned your expected output?

Comment: @KunduK The expected output is to store all the data from the table to a CSV file.

Comment: You need to do lot of things.Create list for start_date and end_date since date range allow for one month only.I have done some working code for you however you have to create those list and iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Induce `WebDriverWait` And `element_to_be_clickable`()
2. **Install** Beautiful soup library
3. Using **pandas** `read_html`()
4. I haven't create list. you should create startdate and enddate list and itearte for all those month since `1/1/2005`

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   import pandas as pd
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import time
   urlpage = 'http://www.sotaventogalicia.com/en/real-time-data/historical'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Shresth Suman/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get(urlpage)
   WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"frame_historicos")))
   inputstartdate=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputInner'])[1]")))
   inputstartdate.clear()
   inputstartdate.send_keys("1/1/2005")
   inputenddate=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputInner'])[last()]")))
   inputenddate.clear()
   inputenddate.send_keys("1/31/2005")
   WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='form-submit'][@value='REFRESH']"))).click()
   WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table#taboa")))
   time.sleep(3)
   soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
   table=soup.find("table", id="taboa")
   df=pd.read_html(str(table))
   df.to_csv('testsot.csv')
   print(df)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works for a particular month. I will try to iterate for the whole period now.